# How to grant an app access to a instagram account without prompting a dialog?

Tags: api, curl, oauth, instagram

I need to implement an Instagram Feed for a website. The only way to access the photos of one specific user is to authorize and grant the app. My problem is, that I want to access a web app instead of individual users with instagram. What approach can I use to stop instagram from prompting the grant-dialog to the users when using the web application which is connected to the web-app-instagram account?

I tried to authorize the client via:

`curl -X POST https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token -d "grant_type=password&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET"`

And got the error:

`{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "This client is not xAuth enabled"}%`

I hope you can help me...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No I moved forward and let this behind me. Sorry.